# Raw Java Class Files?

Tags: java, class

I'm wondering why when I open a raw .class file in something like notepad (I'm using notepad++) why is most text replace with NUL or something like that?

I'm not expected readable code but I don't understand this.

Comment: Class files are bytecode. Why would you expect anything readable in there?

Answer (score 5):

Because a `.class` file is a binary file and `notepad` tries to convert the content to text. And it's printing the corresponding character of what it's finding, most of the times not in `a-zA-Z0-9` range.